# Android Studio xml problem in toolbar/topbar/actionbar

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

Im currently working on a personal project for my mom because she loves plants/flowers so I decided to make an app and I got into a problem in the process of making a toolbar/actionbar/topbar (I dont really know which name to refer because I researched a lot and everyone gives different names I guess)

So to the problem..

**The design I've made and want as final result:**

[My objective is something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21zsP.png)
[and this for the navigation drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cehQL.png)

Currently after some research and trying to understand navigation drawers and toolbars which I find hard to understand at the moment because feels so clunky and confusing I got this:

[toolbar/actionbar/topbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbWJB.png)
[and this as drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I4UnY.png)

The problem is that I can't add the cart icon, I made a menu as well to add it and it just doesn't appear

**My menu**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/tool_cart"
        android:contentDescription="@string/cart"
        android:icon="@drawable/cart_icon"
        android:title="@string/cart"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

**My drawer**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_home"
            android:title="@string/home"
            android:icon="@drawable/home_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_promotions"
            android:title="@string/promotions"
            android:icon="@drawable/promotion_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_gallery"
            android:title="@string/gallery"
            android:icon="@drawable/gallery_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_order_history"
            android:title="@string/old_shipping_orders"
            android:icon="@drawable/history_icon"/>

    </group>

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_account"
            android:title="@string/account"
            android:icon="@drawable/name_acc_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_about_us"
            android:title="@string/about_us"
            android:icon="@drawable/about_us_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_settings"
            android:title="@string/settings"
            android:icon="@drawable/setings_icon"/>

        <item android:id="@+id/nav_log_ou"
            android:title="@string/log_off"
            android:icon="@drawable/logout_icon"/>

    </group>
</menu>
```

**My activity xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/light_green_bg"
    tools:context=".Home"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible">


        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways|snap"
            android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/dark_green_bg"
            android:elevation="6dp"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_cart"
            android:theme="@style/App.ToolbarStyle"
            app:titleTextAppearance="@style/App.ToolbarTitleTex"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:titleTextColor="@color/light_green_bg" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/brown"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/header_nav_drawer"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/brown"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_drawer"
        />


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar
            android:id="@+id/bottomAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            app:fabAnimationMode="slide"
            app:fabCradleMargin="10dp"
            app:fabCradleRoundedCornerRadius="20dp">

            <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
                android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav" />
        </com.google.android.material.bottomappbar.BottomAppBar>

        <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabChat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="68dp"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_icon"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/fab_3_rounded"
            android:contentDescription="TODO" />

    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**My Home.kt**

```
class Home : AppCompatActivity() {

        private lateinit var binding: ActivityHomeBinding

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            binding = ActivityHomeBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)

            binding.bottomNavView.background = null
            // binding.bottomNavView.menu.getItem(2).isEnabled = false

            setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
            supportActionBar!!.setTitle(R.string.app_name_spaced)
            binding.navViewHome.bringToFront()

            val toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,binding.drawerLayout,binding.toolbar,R.string.drawer_open,R.string.drawer_closed)
            binding.drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
            toggle.syncState()
/*            binding.navViewHome.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this)
            binding.navViewHome.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home)*/

    }


    override fun onBackPressed() {
        if(binding.drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
            binding.drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START)
        }
        else{
            super.onBackPressed()
        }
    }

}
```

Before I asked here I tried to find the solution to put the icon appearing such as the first image and the text on the center but I just cant find it or make it work somehow, so again I'm asking help and guidance on the problem or the code it self.

I'am a student and I try to learn/put in practice languages that I feel like doing personal projects on in my spare time any suggestion or help is really appreciated!

**UPDATE**
I found out people actually have the same thing with the support action bar but I cant seem to make it work without it

Comment: Card icon is not really a part from your drawer. It's added as an option menu. You can find more about different menus here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus

Comment: Drop the `MaterialToolbar` into the `ConstraintLayout` maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I GOT THE SOLUTION IN CASE SOMEONE SEARCHES FOR THE SAME THING AS ME**

Basically you will need to override the *setSupportActionBar* in case you use it like me.

**EXAMPLE**

```
override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_cart, menu)

        return true
    }
```